# How to do switch case with return value in function with char in C programming?

Tags: c, function, char, switch-statement

I am new to C programming, trying to do an Assignment for my class.
I am trying to return char value in this function while using switch case.
As an example,
if i were to to put 'a', i expect 'b' to come out as the output.

```
#include <stdio.h>

char *upgrade(char plan);

int main()
{
    char plan;
    printf("what is your plan \n");
    scanf("&s",&plan);
    upgrade(plan);
    printf("\n%s",plan);
}

char *upgrade(char plan)
{
    switch(plan)
    {
        case 'a':
            plan = 'b';
        case 'b':
            plan = 'c';
    }
    return plan;
}
```

Every time I try to do so, the error "[warning] reutrn makes pointed from integer without a cast" comes.
What exactly happens and how do i fix it?

Comment: Your `scanf()` is undefined behavior, you can't store a string (`%s`) in a single `char`. Use `%c` to get a single character, and check the return value since it can fail.

Comment: The variable `plan` is a *single* character, not a null-terminate string (which requires an *array* of characters).

Comment: Also, what does your text-books say about `switch` and how cases *fall through*?

Comment: Decide whether you want to modify the caller's value directly, or just return a new value and allow the caller to do whatever they want. Currently, you're attempting to do both, but it appears you have not yet read the chapters from your introductory book on C that deals with functions, parameters, return values, and pointers.

Comment: In your own words, where the code says `char *upgrade(char plan)`, exactly what do you think that means? Specifically, what do you think the `char *` part means? What do you believe is the declared **return type**? Now, where the code says `return plan;`, what do you think is the type of `plan`? Does it make sense to return that from a function that returns `char *`? Do you see the problem now?

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of problems with the code as posted.

Here's a fixed version, with comments:

```
#include <stdio.h>

char upgrade(char plan); // Return just a char, no pointer.

int main(void) // use void for no arguments
{
    char plan;
    printf("what is your plan \n");
    if (scanf("%c",&plan) == 1) // use % (not &), single char, check return
    {
      plan = upgrade(plan);  // store the upgraded value
      printf("\nYour upgraded plan is: %c\n", plan); // print single character, not a string
    }
    return 0;  // main() returns int.
}

char upgrade(char plan)  // return plain char, no pointer
{
    switch (plan)
    {
        case 'a':
            plan = 'b';
            break;   // use break to prevent fall-through
        case 'b':
            plan = 'c';
            break;
    }
   return plan;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
scanf("&s",&plan);
```

you don't want `&s` but `%c` which is the format specifier for a `char` in `scanf`.

```
upgrade(plan);
```

you want

```
plan = upgrade(plan);
```

in order to alter the variable `plan` in `main`, but the prototype should be `char upgrade(char plan);` instead of `char *upgrade(char plan);` (`return` a `char` not a pointer to it)

Finally, put a `break` after the `case`s, otherwise:

```
    case 'a':
        plan = 'b';
        // there is a fallthrough to the next case
    case 'b':
        plan = 'c';
```